# Дата "С" - "По" добавить в массив

Tags: jquery, массивы

У меня есть следующие даты, например 26.12.2018 и 10.01.2019. Как перечислить или добавить в массив все даты находящиеся в диапазоне с 26.12.2018 по 10.01.2019? Чтобы получилось так:

```
var date = ["26.12.2018","27.12.2018"..."10.01.2019"];
```

Comment: Перебрать в цикле от начала и до конца с шагом в день, запихивая текущее в массив.

Comment: Да, мне нужен например массив дат с "26.12.2018" - по "10.01.2019".

Comment: Ну и обрабатывайте в цикле. Генераторов тут нет, чай не SQL сервер... получится что-то типа `for(i=datestart;i<=dateend;i+=1day){dates.push(i);}` - с точностью до синтаксиса, понятно...

Comment: @Meine какое это отношение имеет к вопросу?

Comment: @AK спасибо, уяснил :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Отвечу сам:

```js
var startDate = new Date("2018-12-26");
var endDate = new Date("2019-01-10");

var getDateArray = function(start, end) {
    var arr = new Array();
    var dt = new Date(start);
    while (dt <= end) {
        arr.push(new Date(dt));
        dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + 1);
    }
    return arr;
}

var datearr = getDateArray(startDate, endDate);
   
for (var i = 0; i < datearr.length; i++) {
    console.log(datearr[i]);
}
```